# Table Self Join for Year over Year comparison

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I am having trouble self joining a table of data to provide year over year results in a single row.

My Data is currently stored as follows in table sales. I can work with either Postgres or sqlite3.

we(date) | store | category | planu | planrev | merchu | merchrev

by desired outcome is:
[image: excel mockup]

I need to be able to show values for LY for 1/7/17 in the last 4 columns.

I will then union the results with those for all other partners replicating the same query for other tables.

It can be assumed that all current year data will be we>1/1/18 to match the date 364 days ago for previous year results.

Through reading other posts I think I may need to craft a CTE query, I just don't know where to start.

I hope this was clear.

Any help in working this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to join on identical store and category as well as same month and day of the year. That would look as follows in PostgreSQL:

```
select 
  'PartnerA' as channel,
  cy.we as date,
  cy.month,
  cy.year,
  cy.store,
  'PartnerA ' || cy.store as ch_store,
  cy.category,
  cy.planu,
  cy.planrev,
  cy.merchu,
  cy.merchrev,
  ly.planu as planu_ly,
  ly.planrev as planrev_ly,
  ly.merchu as merchu_ly,
  ly.merchrev as merchrev_ly
from sales cy
join sales ly on cy.store = ly.store and cy.category = ly.category
  and cy.we - interval '1 year' = ly.we
;
```

Comment: This is perfect. I really appreciate the query. This was a much easier approach than I thought it would be. I didn't consider the interval function, which was really the missing piece.

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for accepting my answer :) In case you also want results where there is no matching row of the previous year, replace `join` by `left outer join`, and maybe `ly.planu` by `coalesce(ly.planu, 0)` (and similar for the other `ly` columns. And always mind leap years ;-) Have fun!